# Can't get rid of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, duplicates

I have my query:

```
SELECT   t.nCitiesId
    ,t.tmDate
    ,t.strShortWeekdayName
    ,t.nIsHoliday
FROM    #temp AS t
WHERE   1 = 1
AND     t.nCitiesId = 104
AND     t.tmDate = '2014-06-08'
GROUP BY t.tmDate, t.nCitiesId, t.strShortWeekdayName, t.nIsHoliday
```

This generates following result:

```
nCitiesId         tmDate              strShortWeekdayName   nIsHoliday
104       2014-06-08 00:00:00.000            SUN                0
104       2014-06-08 00:00:00.000            SUN                1
```

My problem is when nCitiesId and tmDate is equal, I wan't the one with nIsHoliday = 0 gone.

How can I make this in a smooth way?

Comment: what if you also have a third row with `nIsHoliday` = 0, you want final value of the column as 0 or 1?

Comment: As long as tmDate and nCitiesId is equal i only want one row. Always. With nIsHoliday = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick the t.nIsHoliday with highest value:

```
SELECT t.nCitiesId
      ,t.tmDate
      ,t.strShortWeekdayName
      ,max(t.nIsHoliday)
FROM   #temp AS t
WHERE  t.nCitiesId = 104
AND    t.tmDate = '2014-06-08'
GROUP BY t.nCitiesId, t.tmDate, t.strShortWeekdayName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using having clause:

```
SELECT   t.nCitiesId
    ,t.tmDate
    ,t.strShortWeekdayName
    ,t.nIsHoliday
FROM    #temp AS t
WHERE   1 = 1
AND     t.nCitiesId = 104
AND     t.tmDate = '2014-06-08'
GROUP BY t.tmDate, t.nCitiesId, t.strShortWeekdayName, t.nIsHoliday
having max(t.nIsHoliday)
```